# How to return user or group in SharePoint Designer custom activity?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-activity, designer-workflow

How can I return a user or group in SharePoint Designer custom activity?

A return type of SPUser seems to be not possible. SharePoint Designer workflow does not recognize the return type.

```
public static DependencyProperty ResultProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Result", typeof(SPUser), typeof(ApproverDelegatesLookup));

[DescriptionAttribute("the result")]
[BrowsableAttribute(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[ValidationOption(ValidationOption.Required)]
public SPUser Result
{
    get { return (SPUser)GetValue(ResultProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ResultProperty, value); }
}


    <Parameter Name="Result" Direction="Out" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser, Microsoft.SharePoint" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this helps but you could try this:

Lookup user info is the custom activity that you can use:
http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

and/or

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/f97b9b37-a667-44e3-abfe-100f07e27154/